# Agendar execução processo em C#

Tags: c#, .net, agendamento

Tenho uma aplicação que ficará em execução 24h/dia os 7dias/semana, ou seja, estará sempre em execução.

Preciso que em um horário especifico, todos os dias um método dessa aplicação seja chamado.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 18):

Há uma grande possibilidade de você apenas precisar agendar uma tarefa no sistema operacional que chama algo que você precise, eventualmente que se comunique com sua aplicação. No Windows, por exemplo, pode usar o Task Scheduler.

Se quiser realmente fazer dentro da aplicação pode tentar fazer tudo na mão com [a classe de agendamento de tarefas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) ou com [a classe `Timer`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) ou melhor ainda, usar uma biblioteca com a [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/). Outras:

- [Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper](https://github.com/dahall/taskscheduler)
- [A New Task Scheduler Class Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2407/A-New-Task-Scheduler-Class-Library-for-NET)
- [Chroniton](https://github.com/leosperry/Chroniton)

Tem várias implicações em fazer por conta própria e a maioria das pessoas não entendem todas. As bibliotecas ajudam resolver algumas mas não todas. Agendar tarefas dentro da própria aplicação não costuma ser uma boa ideia a não ser que você domine totalmente o assunto que não é simples. Tem um monte de problemas que precisam ser gerenciados e o que parecia simples se torna uma enorme dificuldade.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Chroniton has been improved. It also now supports .NET Core

Answer (score 6):

> Devo ressaltar que a resposta do @Maniero explica como fazer. Irei apenas mostrar um *framework* que uso para isso e me atende. Mas como é uma ferramenta de terceiros, pode não atender algum dia.

Para agendar métodos em `C#`, você pode utilizar o [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) para isso. Ele pode ser instalado via NuGet com o seguinte comando:

```
PM> Install-Package Hangfire
```

Após isso, basta configurar o caminho para o banco de dados, onde será salvo as tasks à ser executadas, desta forma:

```
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .UseColouredConsoleLogProvider()
                .UseSqlServerStorage(@"Server=.\sqlexpress;Database=DataBaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;")
                .UseMsmqQueues(@".\Private$\hangfire{0}", "default", "critical");
```

E para configurar os métodos, você pode utilizar `Cron` ou `TimeSpan`. Um exemplo ficaria assim:

```
 RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!"), Cron.Daily);
```

Onde você altera o `Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!")` pelo método que deseja ser chamado diariamente.

Ele funciona para aplicações Web ou Desktop, alterando apenas os parâmetros de configuração.

Qualquer detalhe, pode olhar [a documentação oficial.](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Em um caso semelhante utilizei WebJob do Azure, onde precisava consumir uma API em determinado intervalo de tempo.
Referencia:
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs

- Implementei em console application um app para consumir a api e executar as tarefas que seriam necessárias, no meu caso enviar um e-mail.
- Compilei o projeto, compactei os arquivo do bin/Release do consoleApp em formato .ZIP.
- Criei um WebJob no meu projeto publicado no Azure.
- Durante a configuração utilizei uma expressão CRON para executar meu consoleApp a cada x tempo.
  https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs#cron-expressions
- Por fim basta startar o webJob. Pronto.
  Bem simples e possui log.
  Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode criar um serviço.

http://www.devmedia.com.br/criando-um-servico-utilizando-c/22912
https://guilerme18.wordpress.com/2014/01/28/windowsservicesvs2012/

Segue exemplo

```
      //definição da thread
        private Thread _ThreadVerificacao;

        public Backup()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            //criação da thread de verificação e sua execução
            _ThreadVerificacao = new Thread(VerificarHorario);
            _ThreadVerificacao.Start();
        }

        //irá verificar se deve ou não executar o método a cada 1 hora
        protected void VerificarHorario()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 10) //Se for 10 horas da manhã
                {
                    RealizaBackup();

                }
                Thread.Sleep(3600000); //3.600.000 milisegundos equivalem a 1 hora
            }
        }

        protected void RealizaBackup()
        {
            //Aqui vai o método que realiza o backup
        }
```

Comment: Esta é uma solução simplista coberta de problemas.

Comment: Se não entendeu pergunte. Esse é apenas um simples exemplo para que você adapte a sua necessidade.