# Executar rotina de minuto em minuto com C#

Tags: c#

Bom dia, estou com um problema que ainda não consegui resolver, tenho uma rotina que irá monitorar um equipamento a cada segundo e ao vira o minuto o sistema irá efetuar a ação desejada, a rotina precisa ler a cada segundo pois o valor de minuto será fornecido pelo equipamento(um PLC AllenBradley). Quando vira o minuto, faço todo processo de coleta, porém ele está repetindo várias vezes o processo gerando duplicidade. Como estou usando Windows Forms, coloquei o tempo para ser contado em um componente Timer do Windows Forms.
Assim que vira o minuto, ele ativa minha função como deveria ser só que ele repete a mesma ação várias vezes, já tentei colocar um sleep, tentei parar o timer(timer1.stop) e nada resolveu. Alguém pode me dar um luz?
Grato.

Segue código
timer e timer_tick

```
private void InitializeTimer(string tTimer, string ipPLC)
    {
        try
        {

            ethernet.IPAddress = ipPLC;
            timeHour = Convert.ToInt16(ethernet.Read("HORA[4]"));// pega o minuto para comparação

            timer1.Interval = Convert.ToInt16(tTimer);
            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);

            //Habilita o timer
            timer1.Enabled = true;


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            if (timeHour != Convert.ToInt16(ethernet.Read("HORA[4]")))
            {

                timeHour = Convert.ToInt16(ethernet.Read("HORA[4]"));

                if (ethernet.Read("HORA[4]").Length < 2)
                {
                    minuto = "0" + ethernet.Read("HORA[4]");
                }else
                    minuto = ethernet.Read("HORA[4]");

                tasgPojoList = new List<TagsPojo>();

                tagsPojo = new TagsPojo();
                tagsPojo.Id_Tag = 1;//fixo para testes
                tagsPojo.ValueTag = float.Parse(ethernet.Read("Program:Etanol3.FT141001_xTot"), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                tagsPojo.Hour = ethernet.Read("HORA[3]") + ":" + minuto;
                tasgPojoList.Add(tagsPojo);

                tagsPojo = new TagsPojo();
                tagsPojo.Id_Tag = 2;//fixo para testes
                tagsPojo.ValueTag = float.Parse(ethernet.Read("Program:Etanol0.FT141002_xTot"), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                tagsPojo.Hour = ethernet.Read("HORA[3]") + ":" + minuto;
                tasgPojoList.Add(tagsPojo);


               CadTagController cadTagController = new CadTagController();
               cadTagController.CadTag(tasgPojoList);

               System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);                    

            }


            label21.Text = "Hora: " + ethernet.Read("HORA[3]");
            label22.Text = "Minutos: " + ethernet.Read("HORA[4]");

            label23.Text = "Segundos: " + ethernet.Read("HORA[5]");

        }
        catch (Exception EF)
        {

           // MessageBox.Show(EF.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Inserção BD-> dados duplicando aqui

```
public void InsertTagH(List<TagsPojo> tags)
    {
        try
        {

            StringBuilder sqlCreateDBQuery1 = new StringBuilder();

            tmpConn = new SqlConnection();
            tmpConn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnString"].ConnectionString;

            DateTime dataNow = DateTime.Now;
            string formataData = dataNow.ToString();
            formataData = formataData.Substring(0, 10);

            foreach (TagsPojo tagsPojo in tags)
            {
                tmpConn.Open();                    

                sqlCreateDBQuery1.Append("INSERT INTO ColetaH(Value, Data, Hour, Id_tag) VALUES(@Value, @Data, @Hour, @Id_tag);");

                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlCreateDBQuery1.ToString(), tmpConn);

                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", tagsPojo.ValueTag);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", FData(formataData));
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hour", tagsPojo.Hour);
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_tag", tagsPojo.Id_Tag);                    

                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                tmpConn.Close();

                //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }


        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Poderia adicionar o código de como está fazendo até o momento?

Comment: Veja se te ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81084/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30601/101

Comment: Não sei se isso iria te ajudar, mas no bloco try...catch, coloque um bloco finally e "zere" todas as variáveis, conexões e etc.... Isso garante no próximo minuto não ter nenhuma informação.