# Chamar função a cada intervalo de tempo com eficiência

Tags: c#, console, timer

Tenho uma dúvida, estou fazendo um servidor de um jogo e preciso que uma função especifica seja rodada a cada 10 segundos.

Eu sei que existe o `Thread.Sleep()` (em combinaçao com um `while(true)`), mas não me parece uma boa opção

Ouvi falar de `Timers` (tentei usar, mas por algum motivo ele só chama a primeira vez e depois para) e de `Windows Services`.

Como faço uma função ser chamada a cada intervalo de tempo de forma eficiente?

Comment: Está utilizando algum banco de dados?

Comment: Estou sim, uso o SQL Server

Comment: Veja se [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/135097/20615) lhe ajuda. Com o [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) você consegue fazer com que uma função seja executada, em segundo plano, com o tempo que deseja.

Comment: @Randrade para o caso dele não será possivel usar o Hangfire, infelizmente o `Recurring jobs` recebe um `CRON schedule`para definir o tempo, e o menor intervalo que se pode definir usando um [CRON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression) é de 1 minuto.

Comment: @TobyMosque Depende da forma que ele quer utilizar. Você pode configurar os 10 segundos como o tempo que ele busca as jobs no banco, e não por CRON. Caso seja apenas para isso.

Comment: @TobyMosque Vale lembrar que [o github deles](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/167) já possuem algumas issues para essa questão.

Comment: Você deve tomar cuidado com o Timer, pois ele vai ser executado a cada 10 segundos independente se o último processo já terminou ou não.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Há a possibilidade de fazer também com [Reactive Extensions](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET), assíncrono com base em eventos.

Adicione o pacote via nuget

> Install-Package System.Reactive

```
var observable = Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
        //.Do((x) => { }) // log events 
    ;

//primeiro subscriber
observable.Subscribe((x) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"multiplica {x} x 2 = {x * 2}");
});

//segundo subscriber
observable.Subscribe((x) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"potência {x}^2 = {Math.Pow(x, 2)}");
});
```

Dessa forma várias ações poderão responder (*subscribers*) a esse gerador de eventos, na minha opinião deixa o código mais bem estruturado.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente  =)
só gostaria de dizer que nome do pacote mudou de Rx-Main  para System.Reactive
obrigado =)

Comment: O pacote [Rx-Main](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rx-Main/2.3.0-beta1) era a versão anterior 2.0, realmente a versão 3.0 mudou o id do pacote.

Answer (score 6):

### Usando timers

> Gera um evento após um intervalo definido, ao intuito de gerar eventos
>   recorrentes.

Use o [`Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.timers.timer.autoreset(v=vs.110).aspx) da seguinte maneira:

```
public class Servidor
{
public static System.Timers.Timer _timer;
public static void Main()
{

    _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    _timer.AutoReset = false;
    _timer.Interval = 1000; // Intervalo em milésimos
    _timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(executarTarefa);
    _timer.Enabled = true;
}

static void executarTarefa(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    _timer.Enabled = false;
    // Seu código
    _timer.Enabled = true;
}
```

Não esqueça da propriedade [`AutoReset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.timers.timer.autoreset(v=vs.110).aspx), pois se ela estiver como `true`, ele executará somente uma vez, como descrito na sua pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado, eu nao sabia essa to AutoReset, ajudou bastante =)

Comment: Seria interessante na execução do evento `executarTarefa` desabilitar o timer na entrada.

Isso evita que por exemplo, se a ação demorar mais de 10 segundos e depender de estado (exemplo enviar emails para quem ainda não recebeu), esses emails serão enviados novamente se o estado não foi alterado.

Answer (score 0):

Entendo que está aberto à opções, então segue mais uma:

## TopShelf

Ele cria um ambiente bem simples para criar Windows Services com temporizadores.

Basta instalar [TopShelf NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Topshelf/) no seu projeto `Console Application`:

> Install-Package Topshelf

Depois, de uma forma muito elegante, crie seu serviço:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HostFactory.Run(configurator =>
        {
            configurator.Service<MeuServicoPeriodico>(s =>
            {
                s.ConstructUsing(name => new MeuServicoPeriodico());
                s.WhenStarted((service, control) => service.Start(control));
                s.WhenStopped((service, control) => service.Stop(control));
            });
            configurator.RunAsLocalSystem();
            configurator.SetDescription("Sobre meu serviço periódico");
        });
    }
}
```

Depois, crie o *container* que irá disparar e controlar o ciclo de vida de seu serviço:

```
public sealed class MeuServicoPeriodico: ServiceControl
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;

    public MeuServicoPeriodico()
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }

    public bool Start(HostControl hostControl)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                // Funções do seu aplicativo vão aqui

                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            }
        }, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);

        return true;
    }

    public bool Stop(HostControl hostControl)
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        _cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Sim, ele utiliza o "conceito" de `while-true-sleep`, mas esse loop fica em uma task onde seu serviço tem pleno controle sobre seu ciclo de vida. Podendo pausar, parar e reiniciar a partir do painel de serviços do Windows - ou a parti de qualquer outro lugar que se possa fazer gestão de serviços.

Veja mais detalhes nesse artigo sobre como criar [Windows Service com TopShelf](http://blog.albertomonteiro.net.br/2016/04/12/criando-windows-service-com-c-de-forma-facil/).

Site oficial [TopShelf](https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf).

Answer (score -2):

Eu já usei Timers, pra mim deu certo, aqui um exemplo de código:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.Interval = 1000; //1000 milésimos = 1 segundo
timer.Enabled = true;
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Time_Elapsed);
```

Agora é só você criar o Event Handler e colocar dentro dele oque você quer:

```
private void Time_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //Alguma coisa
}
```

Obs: Lembre de colocar o `using System.Timers;`

Comment: Vale lembrar que se a propriedade `AutoReset` estiver como true, ele vai executar o "Alguma coisa" somente uma vez.

Comment: Mas por padrão ela está desabilitada não é mesmo meu caro?